# How to Update contact in Journey Builder with ampscript variable

Tags: journeybuilder

I would like to update contacts through a journey builder flow. I can easily use the update contact canvas feature to update a column with static text, but this is not very powerful. I would prefer to use this to update the destination DE with newly input content. For example: A form is filled that requests the contacts favorite color. The DE that is connected to the form is a triggered DE that manages the autoresponder and simplifies the form fill creation process. I have another DE that is used as a repository for this information called user_profile. I would like to update the contact in user_profile to write the %%color%% that the people filled out.

I do not want to do a filter decision for each option and then a manually write the color inside a canvas update contact event since this would be incredibly time consuming and not include every possible outcome.

Am i going about this the wrong way? I assumed ampscript would work here but it doesn't seem to. I am using SalesforceMarketingCloud.